# My g_thread_push is not working

Tags: c, threadpool

I am trying to create a multi-thread, jpg rotation program but I am having problems getting g_thread to work.

```
int processUserRequest (UserRequest *uRequest,
            char * const* argv, int argc, int optind){
  struct RotationData CurData;
  CurData.argv=argv;
  CurData.argc=argc;
  CurData.optind=optind;
  CurData.uRequest=uRequest;
  gpointer user_data = &CurData;
  int transform = FALSE;
  int max_files = argc - optind;
  int i;
  gpointer data=&i;
  GThreadPool *pool;
  if(!g_thread_supported())
       g_thread_init(NULL);

  pool = g_thread_pool_new(MultiThreadRotation,user_data, 5, TRUE, NULL);
  for(i=0;i
  { 
    g_thread_pool_push(pool, &data,NULL);
  }
  //g_thread_pool_free (pool, TRUE,TRUE);
  //Create a montage file
  transform = createMontageFile (uRequest);
  return transform;
}
```

The function MultiThreadRotation is suppose to be called by g_thread_pool_push, but it is not being good once. Can anyone help, I am quite the novice.

Also, I thought about outputting the error from g_thread_pool_push, how would you output a GError *error message?

Answer (score 1):

First off, in the code you pasted, there's a bug in the for statement.

Assuming that's fixed, here are a few remarks.

1. I'm not sure why this is failing, but you can get some indication from the GError's "message" member, which is a human-readable C string you can use with printf() or whatever you like. Unfortunately, you've set the GError arguments to NULL in the g_thread_*() calls.
2. This routine leaks the thread pool; you should call g_thread_pool_free() before exiting it.
3. If you're doing other threading in your program, and you care about performance, you should think carefully about whether you want these threads to be exclusive or shared. That's set with the argument to g_thread_pool_new() which you've set to TRUE (exclusive).